# How to parse dynamic changing response objects in json in asp.netcore

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, json.net

I am having a problem parsing dynamic changing response model in json response

i already tried

```
CryptoMultiPriceViewModel jsonData = 
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CryptoMultiPriceViewModel>(responseData);

public class CryptoMultiPriceViewModel
{
    public RawData RAW { get; set; }   
}

public class RawData
{
    public BTC BTC { get; set; }
}

public class BTC
{
    public STORJ STORJ{ get; set; }
}

public class STORJ
{
    public string TYPE { get; set; }
}
```

that gives me the data but what if the response is changing help i am new to this morepower stackoverflow

this is the response coming from the request the arrow indicates the changing of the response it can be anything: https://ibb.co/XDdgNyB

Comment: Try: `dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseData);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved my problem by creating a model like this

```
public class CryptoMultiPriceViewModel
{
    public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, DataInfo>> RAW { get; set; }   
}

public class DataInfo
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "TYPE")]
    public string dataType { get; set; }
}
```